# Mongo query returns null even though entry is returned by find

Tags: mongodb, null, find, long-integer

In our MongoDb we are implementing the following document structure:

```
Parent
   |-- List<Children>
                |-- ChildField1
                |-- ChildField2
                ...
```

So we have a top level document that contains a list of child documents where each has some members. One of our queries performs a findOne on the value of ChildField1 which is a string. This works as long as the size of the string is not too long. As soon as we store larger strings (in my test it was larger than 1011 chars) we can store the document but the findOne always returns "null".

This happens the same no matter if I use Spring Mongo Data or fire the query in the mongo shell so I figure this is a Mongo issue. When I call find() on the collection all elements are shown but as soon as add a query for the value nothing is returned even by find.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is here and how I can fix it?

Comment: What does your query look like? Is the query string also large or just the method string?

Comment: One scenario when it happens is, when the field on which you are doing find() is indexed. Because there is a limitation on the size of the value for the indexed key for which index entries will be stored. http://pastebin.com/wtWu0ppZ

Comment: As written below, that is exactly our problem here.. thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an index it's likely you're hitting the index limit of 1024 bytes - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/

Comment: Well.. d'oh.. did not catch that in the documentation, thank you.. that is exactly the issue here..